# How to resolve a SparkException when using a User-Defined function?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I need to detect a language by text, and translate that text using PySpark. I could not find any functions for this in PySpark so I created my own UDF's.

**Language detection**

```
def detectlang(string):
    b = TextBlob(string)
    return b.detect_language()

detectlang_udf = udf(detectlang)
```

**Translation**

```
def translate(string):
  trans = Translator()
  return trans.translate(string).text

translate_udf = udf(translate, StringType())
```

However when I call these functions and then ask for the result I get the following error:

```
result = dict_comments[13].withColumn("lang", detectlang_udf(col('Text')))
result.show()

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 15.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 15, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
```

**Edit (full error)**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-256375544159477> in <module>
      1 result = dict_comments[13].withColumn("lang", detectlang_udf(col('Text')))
----> 2 result.show()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    379         """
    380         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 381             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    382         else:
    383             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o872.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 15.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 15, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 480, in main
    process()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 472, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 456, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 149, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 445, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 87, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<command-256375544159470>", line 3, in detectlang
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/textblob/blob.py", line 568, in detect_language
    return self.translator.detect(self.raw)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/textblob/translate.py", line 69, in detect
    raise TranslatorError('Must provide a string with at least 3 characters.')
textblob.exceptions.TranslatorError: Must provide a string with at least 3 characters.

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:534)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:488)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:640)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:528)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1526)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:534)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2360)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2348)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2347)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2347)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1101)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2579)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2527)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2515)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:896)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.runSparkJobs(Collector.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.collect(Collector.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollectResult(limit.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectResult(Dataset.scala:2889)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3501)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2618)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2618)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$54.apply(Dataset.scala:3485)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$54.apply(Dataset.scala:3480)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3480)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2618)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2832)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:265)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:302)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 480, in main
    process()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 472, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 456, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 149, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 445, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 87, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<command-256375544159470>", line 3, in detectlang
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/textblob/blob.py", line 568, in detect_language
    return self.translator.detect(self.raw)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/textblob/translate.py", line 69, in detect
    raise TranslatorError('Must provide a string with at least 3 characters.')
textblob.exceptions.TranslatorError: Must provide a string with at least 3 characters.

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:534)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:488)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:640)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:528)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1526)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:534)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Does anybody know how to resolve this or know of any pre-implemented PySpark functions for my goal?

Comment: can you show glimpse of your data

Comment: I think you cannot use withColumn on column object dict_comments[13] directly. Instead you should use dict_comments.withColumn syntax. Also if you have any error in UDF then you can debug it by logging/printing output in python function detectlang. You can see it in your executor logs.

Comment: @Sri_Karthik the data is of StringType (when I use the python function, not the UDF, then it works).

Comment: @Sagar the object dict_comments is a dictionary that contains Spark dataframes, so calling them by their key returns a Spark dataframe and is not the issue.

Comment: Hi @TiboGeysen, in order to help you, we need the `python` exception. Could you please provide us with whatever comes after `org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):`

Comment: @napoleon_borntoparty I have added the full error

Answer (score 1):

Based on the latest edit, here is the source of your task failure.

```
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/textblob/translate.py", line 69, in detect
    raise TranslatorError('Must provide a string with at least 3 characters.')
textblob.exceptions.TranslatorError: Must provide a string with at least 3 characters.
```

Spark can sometimes be quite unhelpful in providing errors, so here you need to search all the way for your `python` exception, as the driver will only say something like `Task Lost` or `Task Failed`.

A quick fix to your function is then checking on the `len()` of the input string, or adding a `f.when().otherwise()` in `pyspark` on your function call - this might be more desirable as you will not execute your `udf` when not needed. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: When I add a check in my code so that it only detects language of strings with more than 3 characters len(string) < 3, the error still persists.